# How to add Bootstrap class to element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, firebase

I'm getting this error from the console:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The
>   token provided ('si col-md-4') contains HTML space characters, which
>   are not valid in tokens.

This is my HTML snippet, I want to append the div to the row:

```
<div id = 'data' class="container">
<div id = 'row1' class = 'row'>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript code:

```
var row = document.getElementById('row1');
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('si col-md-4');
row.append(div);
```

I should also note that I'm using a firebase database to get the information I want to append.

Answer (score 1):

Use `,` separator if you want to add/remove several classes.

```
div.classList.add('si','col-md-4');
```

If you only need to add the class `col-md-4`,

```
div.classList.add('col-md-4');
```

Comment: It would also be ok, if he adds like this: div.classList.add('si'); div.classList.add('col-md-4'); right?

Comment: Yeah, that way is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

To add multiple class, separate class with ,(comma)

```js
var row = document.getElementById('row1');
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('si', 'col-md-4');
row.append(div);
```

```html
<div id = 'data' class="container">
<div id = 'row1' class = 'row'>
test
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add multiple classes with space seperated as shown below

```
div.className='si col-md-4';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$("#row1").append("<div class='si col-md-4'>Test</div>");
```

```css
.si {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = 'data' class="container">
  <div id = 'row1' class = 'row'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Used jQuery append method.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `.setAttribute("class","si col-md-4")`.It will add the whole new class to it.
As you're adding a class so you should also `.setAttribute("class","previos-class si col-md-4")` do this trick.